# What are the commands in FFmpeg that can be used to fill in the MP3 metadata with my own data?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

What are the commands in FFmpeg that can be used to fill in the MP3 metadata with my own data?

For example, currently I'm using ffmpeg to encode an audio file from MP3 (320k) to MP3 (128k).

These are my metadata commands:

```
commandList.add("-i");
commandList.add(coverPath);

commandList.add("-c");
commandList.add("copy");

commandList.add("-map");
commandList.add("0");

commandList.add("-map");
commandList.add("1");

commandList.add("-id3v2_version");
commandList.add("3");

commandList.add("-write_id3v1");
commandList.add("1");

commandList.add("-metadata:s:v");
commandList.add("title=\"Album cover\"");

commandList.add("-metadata:s:v");
commandList.add("comment=\"Cover (Front)\"");
```

My problem is:

Now I want to add:

```
-metadata [Encoder] && [Encoded by] && [Published by]
```

But I do not know the right commands. Where can I find them? I can't seem to find them in the [FFmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the MP3 section on metadata](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/FFmpeg_Metadata#MP3) on the MultimediaWiki:

> FFmpeg's MP3 muxer creates an ID3v2 tag compatible with either v2.3 or v2.4. The muxer honors the following metadata keys.

Here is the list; reformatting it slightly to fit the formatting on this Stack Exchange site:

```
+---------------------+-----------+
| FFmpeg metadata tag | ID3v2 tag |
+---------------------+-----------+
| "album"             | TALB      |
| "composer"          | TCOM      |
| "genre"             | TCON      |
| "copyright"         | TCOP      |
| "encoded_by"        | TENC      |
| "title"             | TIT2      |
| "language"          | TLAN      |
| "artist"            | TPE1      |
| "album_artist"      | TPE2      |
| "performer"         | TPE3      |
| "disc"              | TPOS      |
| "publisher"         | TPUB      |
| "track"             | TRCK      |
| "encoder"           | TSSE      |
| "lyrics"            | TSLT      |
+---------------------+-----------+
```

Additionally, [check out the this GitHub mirror](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/ee1e39a576977fd38c3b94fc56125d31d38833e9/libavformat/id3v2.c) of [the official FFmpeg source code repository](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git). I dug a bit and found these ID3 related items/maps that might be useful for your purposes:

```
const AVMetadataConv ff_id3v2_34_metadata_conv[] = {
    { "TALB", "album"        },
    { "TCOM", "composer"     },
    { "TCON", "genre"        },
    { "TCOP", "copyright"    },
    { "TENC", "encoded_by"   },
    { "TIT2", "title"        },
    { "TLAN", "language"     },
    { "TPE1", "artist"       },
    { "TPE2", "album_artist" },
    { "TPE3", "performer"    },
    { "TPOS", "disc"         },
    { "TPUB", "publisher"    },
    { "TRCK", "track"        },
    { "TSSE", "encoder"      },
    { "USLT", "lyrics"       },
    { 0 }
};

const AVMetadataConv ff_id3v2_4_metadata_conv[] = {
    { "TCMP", "compilation"   },
    { "TDRC", "date"          },
    { "TDRL", "date"          },
    { "TDEN", "creation_time" },
    { "TSOA", "album-sort"    },
    { "TSOP", "artist-sort"   },
    { "TSOT", "title-sort"    },
    { 0 }
};

static const AVMetadataConv id3v2_2_metadata_conv[] = {
    { "TAL", "album"        },
    { "TCO", "genre"        },
    { "TCP", "compilation"  },
    { "TT2", "title"        },
    { "TEN", "encoded_by"   },
    { "TP1", "artist"       },
    { "TP2", "album_artist" },
    { "TP3", "performer"    },
    { "TRK", "track"        },
    { 0 }
};
```

Comment: This isn't correct a) multimedia.cx isn't official ffmpeg website (or docs); b) Mike (linked site author) has presented the entries from the table of conversion keys for `full key text <--> ID3v2 keys`. This is not the list of keys that ffmpeg will agree to write into an output ID3v2 tag. Give me a couple of days and I'll post the correct list.

Comment: @Gyan For me these all work fine and ffmpeg doesn't complain. What specifically is the problem?

Comment: The ID3v2 writer will add pretty much any random tag in a TXXX frame and demux it correctly as well. However, the list of other allowed TXYZ frames is in a different array and is a superset of the list above. There's also two other tables, for 2.3 and 2.4 specifically, missing at Mike's site as well as above.

Comment: @Gyan Fair enough. When in doubt, [search through the source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/ee1e39a576977fd38c3b94fc56125d31d38833e9/libavformat/id3v2.c).